# Flink BroadcastProcessFunction vs "Broadcast Variables"

Tags: apache-flink

In flink app I need to pass a complex object to all downstream operators. I have found two things for it:

- BroadcastProcessFunction
- "Broadcast Variables"

Could you advise when I should choose one of them and when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadcast variables were about sharing static configuration information during system initialization when doing batch processing with the now defunct DataSet API.

A `BroadcastProcessFunction` is used to process a stream of updates to broadcast state; this is part of the DataStream API. See the docs on [The Broadcast State Pattern](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/broadcast_state/) for more info.

A `BroadcastProcessFunction` or `KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction` is useful when you want to make a relatively small set of data available to all instances of a process function -- i.e., rules used by a rules engine, or foreign currency exchange rates.